# Wordpress White Screen of death UNSOLVABLE

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_custom_background is depreceated since version 3.4.0! Use add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args ) instead. in 

add_custom_image_header is depreceated  since version 3.4.0! Use add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args ) instead. in
```

I am seeing this error messages in the `wp-backend`. The website is displaying a white page. www.etastar.co.in.

Things i tried:

- Disabling Plugins.
- Installing new theme.
- `WP_DEBUG` set to true is also not showing in the front end.
- Increased memory size

How to fix this error? Thank you.

Comment: did you  change anything in functions.php?

Comment: No the site was working fine. Suddenly this white screen of death happend. There was no change made in the WP Backend or in the core files.

Comment: there may be some changes in your function.php file. may be some plugin have made changes if you have used any nulled version plugin. check your error log.

Comment: when in doubt, always check error logs

Comment: [22-Mar-2013 22:40:00] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/suhosin.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/suhosin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I have a whole bunch of errors like this in the error logs.

Comment: this is error from 2013 check for today's date

Comment: [17-Aug-2018 06:56:40 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/etastarc/public_html/wp-content/themes/ETA/functions.php(54) : eval()'d code on line 1
[17-Aug-2018 06:59:11 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/etastarc/public_html/wp-content/themes/ETA/functions.php(54) : eval()'d code on line 1
[17-Aug-2018 07:00:49 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/etastarc/public_html/wp-content/themes/ETA/functions.php(54) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: Did u check the `index.php` for a possible infection?

Comment: Check your functions.php file on line 54, the use of eval() here makes me suspect your website have been infected by malware (which appends code to standard WP files in a theme).

Comment: your function.php fike has been changed. check on line 54 for possible errors or replace it with the old function.php if you have any backup